# Is it a good idea to use a Parser Combinator to parse unstructured input?

Tags: programming-practices, programming-languages, language-design, parsing

I'm writing a parser that needs to accept unstructured input. By that I mean it needs to take in a raw signal (text, in this case) and look for significant character sequences while accumulating the non-signal text.

For example, given the following input:

```
Hello! I am a block of noisy text. This is a \symbol significant symbol \end and the surrounding is not.
```

I should be able to parse out the `\symbol ... \end` characters while still collecting the surrounding text.

I'm using a parser combinator library for this but I have a suspicion that this use case is different from the one most parse combinator libs are built for. Most use cases involve a completely known, structured domain (phone numbers, email addresses, programming languages). The parser applies a set of rules based on closed domain to the input and throws errors for everything it encounters outside of that domain. However, my case (ideally) requires accepting everything outside of the declared domain.

I say ideally because obviously there is a way to use a standard parser combinator to accomplish what I'm trying to do:

```
# pseudo code:
symbol_start = word("\symbol")
symbol_end = word("\end")
word = many(char())
between_sym = between(symbol_start(), symbol_end())
any_text = many(word() + or(space(), word(), punctuation()) + between_sym()
```

I can declare the entire domain of the English language using a set of parsers. However, I find this to be tedious and brittle -- the stability of the final parser would be suspect at best. I'd much rather allow accumulating the raw, noisy blob of text and parsing out the symbols within it:

```
# pseudo code
symbol_start = word("\symbol")
symbol_end = word("\end")
any_text = any_char() + between(symbol_start(), symbol_end())
```

Is this a new kind of problem? Or am I attacking it the wrong way?

Comment: Why was this downvoted???

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.  If your question is "Will my last block of pseudo code do what I want," the answer appears to be "yes."  The "noisy text" isn't significant; the text between your very unique symbols is.

Comment: My question is whether or not it's a good idea to parse unstructured input with a parser combinator. And abstractly, whether or not parser combinators inherently are better for parsing a closed domain instead of an open one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I modified the title.

Comment: Your domain isn't an open one; it is a closed one: extract the text between two well-defined and very unique symbols.  You don't even need a parser to do that. 
 How do you define "good idea?"

Comment: Unless your two symbols are entirely arbitrary (i.e. two random English words), and not very unique at all.

Comment: In any case, without some sort of rubric to decide whether your idea is a "good" one or not, I don't see how this is answerable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see the need for the snark. The question is asking for an opinion. If you have an opinion on the subject, provide it. If not, don't.

Comment: There isn't a trace of snark in any of my responses.  And if you're looking for an opinion rather than an answer, Reddit or Quora are better places.

Comment: While not an open domain, an entire spoken/written language has a large surface area with many complex rules, making it practically open when compared to the types of domains usually used with PCs. Hence the issues that arise when using a PC.

Comment: Yes, but the domain you defined is very specific symbols with text in between them.  So unless you're asking about how to interpret the text once you extract it ...

Comment: Well, I should've mentioned this, but there is a good chance that the set of symbols will expand. I'm looking for a solution that can be expanded to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

Most combinators allow some exclusion sort of parser: "accept all characters except \"

It then becomes pretty straight-forward to make something where your start/end are one parser and "everything else" is another, combined within `zero-or-more(either())` sort of construct.

Where it might fall down is if you require the start/end symbols to be nested. Once you need to start doing things like counting parenthesis you get into context sensitive languages that usually aren't handled well by simple combinators.

Comment: Kinda _OOP State Pattern_ is applicable (regarding most kind of parsers are basically FSM's at all). There are things like _embedded Sub- State Diagrams_ inside of states.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - sure, but not all combinator libraries allow parsers with arbitrary state, and it's... impractical to encode integers into the grammar.